# How to keep focus on input field in Firefox in React

Tags: reactjs, firefox, input

I have an input field like so:

```
 <input
     type="text"
     id="someid"
     autoFocus={true}
     ref={this.inputRef}
/>
```

I am setting `createRef` on the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
   this.inputRef = React.createRef();
}
```

Then on componentDidMount(), I set autofocus to true:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.inputRef.current.autoFocus = true;
}
```

In Chrome, the input field is always autofocused, which is the behaviour that I am expecting. In Firefox, it's focused on mounting however, loses focus when clicking outside the input field.

How do I keep the focus on Firefox even if clicking outside the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check below url. I have created some sample for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hubbxi

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

  } 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusInput()

  }
  focusInput = ()=>{
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

         <input
     type="text"
     id="someid"
     autoFocus={true}
     onBlur={this.focusInput}
     ref={this.inputRef}
/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```